# Getting my python script onto the web

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a python script that runs on the command line and it needs a user input to begin. I would like to implement this script on a website in a way that the user input is from a text field from the website and this input will be passed into the script. Other features of the website will include:

- a login page
- some settings on how often the script will run (user input)

My question: what is the fastest method to get this done?

I am currently in the process of learning Django from scratch which is actually taking quite awhile and I am unsure if this is the best way to go about doing this. Does anyone have any tips for me?

Comment: It actually sounds like Django would be a reasonable choice for what you want. It is much easier to learn than many other frameworks and will be worth the time if you plan on doing similar things in the future. In your specific case, I would suggest to just learn the basics of Django views and templates. Ignore the more advanced features like form validation for now if you don't want to spend too much time on reading the Django docs.

Comment: have a look at Flask as a simpler framework (that you can still extend to be as full featured as you need later)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to dive in into any frameworks you can make single page application and having login password and field in the same page.

```
import web
urls = (
    '/', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        
    def GET(self):
        return 'yourPage'
    def POST(self, data):
         do something
         return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: "web" here must be web.py, which *is* a framework. There is no `web` module in the standard library.

Comment: So learning a framework is the best way to go about doing this?